# Install raspi-config on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: wifi, camera, ubuntu, raspi-config

I download the **Ubuntu Classic Server 16.04 - Raspberry Pi 3** from  https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/ and installed it on my RPi 3.
Now I see that wlan0 is missing.

I don't have /dev/video0 even-though I have a (flex) camera connected.

So I tried to see if it is a configuration matter, but when executed

```
sudo raspi-config
```

I get:

```
sudo: raspi-config: command not found
```

Is that the problem?
If so, how can I install it?

If not, what else can I try in order to make the camera and wifi module to work?

Comment: you will need to do it the linux way, raspi-config works with Raspbian OS only

Comment: any idea what would be the linux way to achieve it?

Comment: Are you with the system? if yes, we can go doing one by one things and see if that works because I am no pro, I can google for you :)

Comment: try this for the wlan : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=939041#p939041

Comment: also check this out : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

Answer (score 1):

`raspi-config` is just a front end to the various configuration files - it is a simple bash script (if long and convoluted), and you could copy it from Raspbian, or find on the web.

Whether it would work is doubtful; while most options should work, networking probably won't as Ubuntu uses `Network Manager` and [predictable network interface names](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#new-interface-names) so `wlan0` won't exist.

`raspi-config` is now installed on Ubuntu Mate for Pi and this may be different to the Raspbian version.

Comment: In my case it did not work, since raspi-config expects `config.txt` and other essential files to be located in `/boot` folder, but in my Ubuntu xenial installation these files are in `/boot/firmware` folder